# Highlight if cell exists in a range in other sheet

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to highlight a row (or cell, if that's easier) if that value exists in a range in an other sheet in the same document.

Details: In Google Sheets, I have one sheet named "Application", with email addresses in column D. In a different different sheet (named "Accepted") I have the same data copied from the application sheet, also in column D.

I want to highlight the cells with email addresses in the "Application" sheet which has been copied over to the "Accepted" sheet.

I know Conditional formatting with Custom formula is the way to go, but I'm unable to find the correct syntax.

What is the correct formula for this?

Comment: Same workbook, but different tabs? Or different Google Sheets file entirely?

Answer (score 1):

In Google Spreadsheets conditional formatting across sheets is not nearly as straightforward as within a single sheet, because of security and therefore authorisation. You may, for speed for example, prefer to copy the content of `Accepted` into `Application` to avoid that issue, or write a script instead. At least keep the ranges as small as practical.

However it is possible, though may be slow and require authorisation.

Please clear any conditional formatting from `Application` ColumnD then:

Select ColumnD in `Application`, Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... `Custom formula is` and

```
=COUNTIFS(IMPORTRANGE("k e y","Accepted!D:D"),D1)>0
```

with highlighting of your choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

`k e y` above represents the unique identification code for `Accepted` (will look something like `1u4vq8vDne-aKMVdJQPREGOxx7n99FqIb_kuJ_bG-PzM`).

Comment: I think OP's comments are again within a single spreadsheet, across worksheets.